# How to enumerate instances of a thread_local variable

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-local

I am using a thread local variable like :

```
static thread_local     int m_counter;
```

for a random number sequence counter.
Using thread_local works very well, i have one instance
per thread.

My problem is that i need to reset these for a new run of my simulation.  I do not have a list of the threads, so i do not have access to each instance.  I want to systematically reset all counters to 0.

Is there a recommended way (in C++ 11 ) to do this ?

My only idea as of now is to use 2 sets of counters like:

```
static thread_local     int m_counter_a;   // counter "a"
static thread_local     int m_counter_b;   // counter "b"
```

Instead of reseting centrally i pass an a,b value to the multithreaded code. Then the counters of the "other" set are reset. This works, but i do repeated resets like 50000 times

```
if (a) {
   m_counter_b = 0;
   m_counter_a++;
} else {
   m_counter_a = 0;
   m_counter_b++;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the repeated resets ?

Comment: How about a vector of `int`, one element per thread? Possibly make it a vector of `std::atomic<int>` if you want to "reset" the value while the threads are still running.

Comment: Oh and if you want a non-negative counter you should probably use `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: You may 'registrer' your  local variable on thread startup by saving pointer to it in some global list. Then you can go through this list and reset values when needed.

Comment: You can have a global array with size = max number of threads. Assign a monotonically increasing thread id to each thread by using another global atomic counter and store this thread id in a thread local variable. use the same thread id to access the slot of the global array. since no one else accesses the slot, there is no sync. primitive required.

Comment: Broadcast a message to all threads and get each thread to reset itself.

Comment: Since you can access the global list, you can traverse and set the values to 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, would it not be inefficient to use `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>` in multiple threads? Scott Meyers' [Cpu Caches and Why You Care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE) talked about cache invalidation problem, when using a global array with threads.

Comment: @badola Maybe, or maybe not. The only way to know is to measure and benchmark and profile. And unless there's a pre-existing requirement about "efficiency" any kind of optimization (which tend to obfuscate code) should be done after measuring and profiling. First and foremost write good, readable, and maintainable code that works and passes through all tests. Then, if it's not "good enough" (and often "good enough" *is* good enough) find the bottlenecks and concentrate on those (with ample documentation and commenting).

Comment: I'm right now in the middle of a similar challenge. I think I'll just spin a new thread for each "simulation run" (quotes, because I'm not really doing simulation...).